# Spock Test for ActiveMQ JMS listener in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, spock

I want to write spock test case for ActiveMQ JMS Listener using spring boot. Can somebody share any idea how to do it. I have followed the steps mentioned here https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/ to create the listener. Below is the code for which I want to write unit test

```
@JmsListener( containerFactory = "myFactory", destination =  "some q")
    public void  processMesg( OrderRequest order ) {
        -------------------------
    }
```

Comment: You want to test a void method - is that your issue? Or do you want to test what happends when a (or a number of) real JMS message is sent? You need to think of what you want to test. Fire of a JMS message in spock setup then assert some expected changes of the application state doesn't seem impossible. But sure it requires some coding.

Comment: @Peter Nordlander: I want help for Spock set up for jms activemq n if I fire some msg to the queue it should be received n processed by my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a small JMS client (or use an existing one) that will be called from your Spock test and it will connect to you JMS queue.

Details on how to do do not fit in a single answer.

In general there is nothing specific about Spock and JMS. You need to have the capability to send custom JMS messages anyway, regardless of the test framework you will use in the end.